# Can I run pdflatex on an in-memory file?

Tags: python, pdflatex

I am to generate a series of pdf files whose contents is to be generated in Python (2.7). A regular solution is to save the .tex contents at some directory, call pdflatex on the file, read in the pdf-file afterwards in order to finally place the file somewhere relevant. This is shown below:

```
import os

texFile = \
"""\\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,final]{article}
\\begin{document}
Hello, world!
\\end{document}
""" # Clearly will a more awesome file be generated here!

with open('hello.tex', 'w') as f:
    f.write(texFile)
os.system('pdflatex hello.tex')
pdfFile = open('hello.pdf', 'rb').read()
# Now place the file somewhere relevant ...
```

I desire the same procedures but comitted on an in-memory basis, for increasing speed and avoiding file leakage into some folder. So my question is, how to run pdflatex on an in-memory basis and extracting the resulting pdf back into Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [tex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tex). It provides an in-memory API to the TeX command line tools. For example:

```
>>> from tex import latex2pdf
>>> document = ur"""
... \documentclass{article}
... \begin{document}
... Hello, World!
... \end{document}
... """
>>> pdf = latex2pdf(document)

>>> type(pdf)
<type 'str'>
>>> print "PDF size: %.1f KB" % (len(pdf) / 1024.0)
PDF size: 5.6 KB
>>> pdf[:5]
'%PDF-'
>>> pdf[-6:]
'%%EOF\n'
```

You can install it by simply running `pip install tex`. Also note that for the string blocks you can simply prepend `r` to make it a raw string. That way you don't have to escape all the backslashes.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have tried it out, but got following error message: ValueError: close_fds is not supported on Windows platforms if you redirect stdin/stdout/stderr. I am using windows 7. I have not been able to find a solution yet, nor could I successfully install its successor "texcaller", wich I think is due to the fact that it have not been packaged for windows. But I am not sure yet.

Comment: This sounds more like a Windows compatibility issue. I am using Linux, so it's not possible for me to reproduce the problem. A quick search reveals how other projects fixed it: [gevent](https://github.com/gevent/gevent/issues/669), [py4j](https://github.com/bartdag/py4j/issues/170), [ipython](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/3244/). Also make sure you're using the most recent package version from PyPI. The ValueError indicates that there was an error with redirects, so pipes under UNIX systems. Do you use Cygwin?

Comment: Beware that `texcaller` still calls `pdflatex` under the hood, writing files on disk, so technically it is not "in-memory". Running `pdflatex` via `subprocess.run` in a temporary directory has the same (or even better) execution time and avoids all the compilation fuzz.